# FFMPEG php HLS and DASH conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm using this repo https://github.com/aminyazdanpanah/PHP-FFmpeg-video-streaming to encode video in hls and then reproduce on the front end.

After creating all the hls segments correctly the php script fail to execute the command below.
The command getting error is the next one:

```
'/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' 'source.mp4' '-c:v' 'libx264' '-c:a' 'aac' '-bf' '1' '-keyint_min' '25' '-g' '250' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-use_timeline' '1' '-use_template' '1' '-init_seg_name' 'dash_init_$RepresentationID$.$ext$' '-media_seg_name' 'dash_chunk_$RepresentationID$_$Number%05d$.$ext$' '-seg_duration' '10' '-hls_playlist' '0' '-f' 'dash' '-adaptation_sets' 'id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a' '-map' '0' '-s:v:0' '256x144' '-b:v:0' '830k' '-map' '0' '-s:v:1' '426x240' '-b:v:1' '969k' '-map' '0' '-s:v:2' '640x360' '-b:v:2' '1162k' '-map' '0' '-s:v:3' '854x480' '-b:v:3' '1453k' '-map' '0' '-s:v:4' '1280x720' '-b:v:4' '1938k' '-map' '0' '-s:v:5' '1920x1080' '-b:v:5' '2907k' '-strict' '-2' '-threads' '12' 'dash.mpd'
```

Here there is the error printed executing the command with CLI:

```
    ffmpeg version 4.3-2~16.04.york1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~16.04.york1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
    libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
    libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
    libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
    libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
    libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
    libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
    libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
    libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
    libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'source.mp4':
    Metadata:
        major_brand     : mp42
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: mp42mp41
        creation_time   : 2020-07-10T09:13:47.000000Z
    Duration: 01:03:27.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3298 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 2977 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2020-07-10T09:13:47.000000Z
        handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
        encoder         : AVC Coding
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
        creation_time   : 2020-07-10T09:13:48.000000Z
        handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
    Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:2 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:3 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:4 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:5 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:6 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:7 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:8 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:9 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:10 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:11 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d5e6c80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d5e6c80] profile High, level 2.0
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d5e6c80] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=1 b_pyramid=0 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=830 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d09fcc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d09fcc0] profile High, level 2.1
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d09fcc0] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=1 b_pyramid=0 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=969 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d0a4240] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d0a4240] profile High, level 3.0
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d0a4240] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=1 b_pyramid=0 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=1162 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d0a8380] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d0a8380] profile High, level 3.0
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d0a8380] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=1 b_pyramid=0 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=1453 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d085c80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d085c80] profile High, level 3.1
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d085c80] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=1 b_pyramid=0 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=1938 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d089d40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d089d40] profile High, level 4.0
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d089d40] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=1 b_pyramid=0 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=2907 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    [dash @ 0x55de2cf50900] Opening 'dash_init_0.m4s' for writing
    [dash @ 0x55de2cf50900] Opening 'dash_init_1.m4s' for writing
    [dash @ 0x55de2cf50900] Opening 'dash_init_2.m4s' for writing
    [dash @ 0x55de2cf50900] Conflicting stream par values in Adaptation Set 1
    Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
    Error initializing output stream 0:10 -- 
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d5e6c80] final ratefactor: 16.04
    [aac @ 0x55de2d09eb80] Qavg: 65536.000
    [aac @ 0x55de2d09eb80] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d09fcc0] final ratefactor: 19.18
    [aac @ 0x55de2d0a2b00] Qavg: 65536.000
    [aac @ 0x55de2d0a2b00] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d0a4240] final ratefactor: 21.16
    [aac @ 0x55de2d0a6c40] Qavg: 65536.000
    [aac @ 0x55de2d0a6c40] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d0a8380] final ratefactor: 21.67
    [aac @ 0x55de2d084540] Qavg: 65536.000
    [aac @ 0x55de2d084540] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d085c80] final ratefactor: 22.63
    [aac @ 0x55de2d088600] Qavg: 65536.000
    [aac @ 0x55de2d088600] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
    [libx264 @ 0x55de2d089d40] final ratefactor: 22.67
    [aac @ 0x55de2d08c5c0] Qavg: 65536.000
    [aac @ 0x55de2d08c5c0] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
    Conversion failed!
```

I checked if I have MPEG DASH support enable and it is enabled in FFMPEG